# Issues incrementing characters in a string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this code:

```
function shift(str) { let newStr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
    newStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt() + 1 //numbers > 1 returns a successful unit test); 
}                                  
    newStr = newStr.join('');

    return newStr; 
}

console.log(shift('pie')); // returns qjf

module.exports = shift;
```

When I console.log my function it properly returns the expected string of qjf, however, when I try to run tests with Jest:

```
test('pie returns qjf', () => [ 
    expect(shift('pie)).toBe('qjf),
 ]);
```

Running tests returns: "test functions can only return Promise or undefined. Returned value: Array [undefined,]". Not sure what I'm doing wrong, thanks for any help!

Comment: It should be `test('pie returns qjf', () => {...})`. Arrow functions use either curly brackets for an explicit return, or parentheses for an implicit one. Not square brackets. And you also have another typo - you're missing a quote around `pie`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using square brackets instead of curly brackets in the test function. This should work:

```
test('pie returns qjf', () => { 
    expect(shift('pie')).toBe('qjf'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test function is wrapped in [] instead of {}.  It also looks like you're missing a single quote in the shift() and tobe() functions parameters.